# Qt Linguist: translation of text changed dynamically in tr()

Tags: qt, translation

I am using qt linguist and qt 5.2. I have a problem that when I add something to .ui files I can see it after lupdate in ts file but when I change name of this button dynamically in my code like:

```
ui->label->setText(tr("foo"));
```

I can't see it in ts file, is it possible to make translation in that case? How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, `tr()` can be detected anywhere in the codes.For ui files, linguist would detect the changes immediately, however in codes I encounterd the same problem.
Based on my experience, try to reBuilt/qmake it.

(I am using Qt4.8 & 5.1.)